# Program design for maintaining a collection of trees

Tags: c++, class, oop, tree

I am trying to maintain a collection of perfect, heap ordered, binary trees:
[image]

(sorry).

So, i would think that creating a *heapNode* type, containing the relevant child/parent pointers and holding an element, and a *heap* type, that would implement the operations on the trees, would be straighforward. At least, this is how i would do it if i had just one tree to worry about. The problem is that, given a pointer to a node in *any* tree, i need to be able to delete that node. But, only given the pointer, i can't figure out how im gonna know what *heap* instance to call.

My idea then, is that i dont have a *heap* type as such, only the nodes, and then a *modifier* type of some sort, that will implement all the tree operations. The only thing this modifier would know about, is how to operate on *heapNodes*( changing links and so on ). I am thinking that the modifier type is just a collection of static methods, maybe just a collection of plain C functions.

Any thoughts on this problem? I would guess that it's a more general problem: given a reference to some (data) member of a class, how can you easily access the operations available on it? I am doing this in C++, which i don't know very well. Im fine with C though. Thanks.

Comment: Is your problem that the root of each tree has to be handled specially?

Comment: Hmm, no. My problem is that say im given a pointer to the root of the second tree in my drawing. I want to delete this node but all i have is the pointer to it. If the nodes are "maintained" through a heap class, i don't know which instance the node belongs to. Thus, i don't know which heap class instance i would call to delete the node. Makes sense?

Comment: if (node.isRoot()) { heap.remove(node); } node.remove();

Comment: But, say each tree is of type heap. These heaps are maintained in a type heapList or similar. Which heap.remove() would i call?

Comment: My problem is not as such to operate on the heaps, but more of a general OOP thing... i think. Say i had a mailbox class that would hold letters. The mailbox would have methods like trash letter, send letter and so on. Then say i instantiate three mailboxes. Now, given only a reference to some letter, not the containing mailbox, i want to, say, trash the letter. I would know which method to call, but not which mailbox object to call it on.

Comment: It is usually a sign of bad design if you have patterns like "if (obj.query_state() == some_state) {obj.do_something();}". The guideline is called Tell, don't ask. In your example, mailboxes should have a trashLetter method which than trashes the letter if it is in the mailbox, otherwise just does nothing. The fundamental principle is that the object is responsible for its data and not somebody outside.

Comment: Yes. But i *know* the letter is in one of the mailboxes, just not which one. I don't want the program to scan all the mailboxes to find the mailbox containing the letter. I probably have around ten million letters, scattered across 20 or so mailboxes.

Comment: Doing nothing in case the letter is not in the mailbox should be a pretty fast no-op, but this is done internally in the mailbox. If you only have a letter, but do not know in which mailbox it is, how would choose the right one with scanning it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you get the pointer into the trees from? IMHO, this violates encapsulation of your tree collection class (if there is none, this may be the problem) and is a sign of missing abstraction. Keep your internals private.

You do know that you can model a heap with an array without using nodes linked by pointers? In C++, the STL provides functions to do this.

```
template<typename T> class Forest {
public:
// functions to do something with the heap,
// but do not leak internals.
void do_something(T const& x) {
    // pick a heap and add an element
    mHeaps[0].push(x);
}

private:
// simple wrapper around STL heap functions
class Heap {
public:
    void push(T const& x) {
        mData.push_back(x);
        std::push_heap(mData.begin(), mData.end());
    }

    T pop() {
        std::pop_heap(mData.begin(), mData.end());
        T const tmp(mData.back());
        mData.pop_back();
    }

    private:
        std::vector<T> mData;
    };

std::vector<Heap> mHeaps;
};
```

If you need iteration, implement a custom iterator to iterate over all heaps, but do not leak internals. Clients should not depend on implementation knowledge, e.g. the way heaps are implemented.

As mentioned in the comments, you are implementing a priority queue using heaps ( cphstl.dk/Paper/TOCS-2011/journal.pdf). I would suggest a design like this:

- A priority queue class that stores a collection of heaps and has the invariant mentioned in page 13 (this is good to check before and after operations for debugging). It also stores the numeral system representation. Let's say that the priority queue keeps a vector member.
- A class to represent the numeral system. This implements a mapping to the heaps in the vector by storing iterators.
- A class representing a single heap with operations to add, remove and elements and merge with other heaps. You could look at std::map for an example of a tree structure.

These elements can be implemented and tested almost individually. Clients of priority queue do not see anything of the implementation.

Comment: Well, if its of interest here is some background: http://www.cphstl.dk/Paper/TOCS-2011/journal.pdf 
But my problem is not the heaps. The user will supply the reference to the node. The forest will implement a priority queue(adressable, meldable). Thus, the user will store pointers to the nodes in their application. The user doesn't know anything about the implementation, but they do know that they can call priority_queue.delete(*node) (or similar)

Comment: The exact details, im not sure about yet. Maybe the user is responsible for supplying a node, containing an element, or they will be returned a reference to the node once it's in the queue. Either way, the user will be able to store these references in his/her apllication. My working prototype is not written with classes and objects. It's "handwritten" C, so i just operate on the nodes and trees as i wish. However, part of the project is to do it in C++. Good OOP design is not my strong side.

Comment: Are you implementing the priority queue with binomial heaps? In an OOP design, I would strongly argue against giving out pointers to internal nodes. One of the key concepts is abstraction meaning that clients should not depend on implementation details or assumptions inside other objects. You could have a look at std::list or std::map. Both provide an abstraction of their internal structure and clients do not have to worry about the implementation of a map.

Comment: It is like a binomial queue yes, but using perfect binary heaps instead. It's a fairly complicated gadget. Probably mostly of theoretical interest, but thats life of a student :)

Comment: But, using std::list couldn't i just store an iterator to an element and then call erase on the list if i wanted to? As far as i understand, std::list iterators are not invalidated by operating on the list.

Comment: std::list also has emplace() that returns an iterator to the inserted node. Then i would keep that iterator, and delete or replace the node later, if i wanted to. Is that such a bad idea?

Comment: That is not a bad idea at all. The iterator is an abstraction of the nodes in the list. It allows you to access  the data in the node, but cannot manipulate internals of the list as when you have a pointer to the internal node. The list can only be manipulated through the list interface, which keeps it under control. But I would create a priority queue class that does all that internally and hides it from client code. And in C++, a vector is often the better choice because it is faster than a list.

Comment: Yes, forgive me, im not used to C++. It doesn't *have* to be an actual, C style pointer. The user just has to be able to adress particular nodes. Like with the 'emplace()' example above. BUT, that still leaves me with the question: when the user calls my priority_queue class with some iterator, or other abstraction, how will the priority_queue class know what heap *instance* to call, if it maintains a collection of them? If i have a priority_queue class that has access to a, say, *heap_modifier* class, i could do it easily. However, im thinking there is a more C++ 'ish approach...

Comment: A priority queue iterator will have to know in which tree it currently is because it has to switch to the next tree when you use it to iterate. It could store an iterator to the collection of heaps which you can query inside the priority queue class, but hide it for clients.

Comment: If for example i had just a single list, i would call emplace(), save the iterator and later i would know what list instance to call. Since there is only one. But if i have, maybe, 3 list's, and save iterators for all 3 of them, i dont have enough information when i need to adress the iterators?

Comment: Hmm, ok. Well, maybe i need to get some sleep and then look into those iterator abstractions. Thanks alot...it was useful!